# How does SQL return a GROUP BY query and how to sum up each group column?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

Let's say i have a table:

```
     ID  ITEM      OWNER   PRICE
     1   phone      joe     150
     2   tablet     joe     220
     3   phone      joe     310
     4   tablet     joe     180
     5   tablet     tom     190
```

and i want to get results grouped according to the item, so i use a query of type "SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY `ITEM`", how will sql will return me the results so i can have them grouped and have total price of each item category going through of each group using PHP? e.g. total phones cost is 460.

Comment: Did you try running the query and looking at the result?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ITEM, SUM(PRICE) AS summedprice FROM tblWhatever GROUP BY ITEM;
```

should do the trick.

If you want more columns, do MUST name them also in the "group by".

for example:

```
SELECT ITEM, OWNER, SUM(PRICE) AS summerprice FROM tblWhatever GROUP BY ITEM, OWNER;
```

Will give you the aggregate results for each ITEM/OWNER combination found.

Answer (score 2):

You will for example use

```
SELECT ITEM, SUM(PRICE) AS TOTAL, COUNT(*) AS NUMBER FROM table GROUP BY ITEM;
```

then SQL will return the item, the total of prices and the number of items. Retrieval in PHP is possible with the keys `ITEM`, `TOTAL` and `NUMBER` via your favourite database interface (PDO or mysqli).

Tools like [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) are very convenient for playing around with stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select sum (price) from table group by item
```

It takes together all rows with the same value in item and sum take together all price values where item is the same and add them together

E.g for phone, sum is 310 plus 150.